# Как реализовать прокрутку при движении шарика по траектории

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-animation

Только начала осваивать анимацию с JS.
Подскажите, как лучше будет реализовать данный полукруг, чтобы в дальнейшим подключить анимацию с возможностью скролла и выбора(клика) определённого текста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это больше похоже на вызов реализовать :D

Comment: Текст-точки, пропадающие снизу - должны появляться сверху, ага?

Comment: Это не вызов реализовать) Просто есть различные варианты, но я не знаю какой выбрать, чтобы в дальнейшем было проще подключать JS  и фильтрацию

Comment: @Liza, это не отменяет тот факт, что вы не предоставили свои примеры (хотя бы попытки), относительно требований форума

Answer (score 11):

Уверен, что есть более практичные методы на JavaScript. Но можно попробовать набор современных инструментов CSS.

Я использовал [offset-path](https://ru.w3docs.com/uchebnik-css/css-svoistvo-offset-path.html), это путь, принимающий значения SVG-пути. Сгенерировать свой вектор SVG можно с помощью [этого иснтрумента](https://codepen.io/anthonydugois/pen/mewdyZ).

[offset-rotate](https://ru.w3docs.com/uchebnik-css/css-svoistvo-offset-rotate.html) задает вращение элемента во время прохождения пути. Если не задать - элемент будет проворачиваться, находясь параллельно вектору.

[offset-distance](https://ru.w3docs.com/uchebnik-css/css-svoistvo-offset-distance.htm) это собственно точка на дистанции нашего вектора, используется в анимации.

Надо понимать, что CSS Motion Path [несколько сыроват](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-motion-paths). Но уже имеет право на рассмотрение.

В дальнейшем можно манипулировать CSS и анимацией из JS.

```css
#red-circle {
  offset-path: path('M 200 50 C 50 150 50 350 200 450');
  offset-rotate: 0deg; 
  animation: move 3000ms infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red; 
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    offset-distance: 0%;
    opacity: .7;
    transform: scale(0.7); 
  }  
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1); 
  }
  100% {
    offset-distance: 100%;
    opacity: .7;
    transform: scale(0.7); 
  }
}

#red-circle .red-title {
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(100% + 15px);
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="red-circle">
  <div class="red-title">Text</div>
</div>
```

### Обновлено

Так как наш вектор - по сути сектор окружности - можем вести себя с ним соответственно. В вопросе сказано, что Вы осваиваете JavaScript и подключать анимацию и скролл будете в дальнейшем. Не буду лишать Вас этого удовольствия. Просто покажу, как можно общаться с окружностью из JS.

```js
let redCircle = document.querySelector("#red-circle"),
    r = 180, // размер окружности 360x360px в CSS
    left = '',
    tops = '',
    alpha = 2 * 3.1415; // не использовал Math.PI, нет необходимости в сверхточности
function drawPosition(t) {
  left = r + r * Math.cos(alpha * t); // первый r определяет центр окружности
  tops = r + r * Math.sin(alpha * t);
  redCircle.setAttribute("style", "left:" + left + "px; top: " + tops + "px; --t: " + t + ";");
  // CSS переменная --t добавлена только, чтобы удобно просмотреть в консоли динамику изменения переменной t
}
requestAnimationFrame(function step(time) {
  drawPosition(time / 10000);  // один оборот за 10 секунд
  requestAnimationFrame(step)
});
```

```css
#red-parent {
  width: 360px;
  height: 360px;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  margin: 70px;
}

#red-circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

#red-circle .red-title {
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(100% + 15px);
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="red-parent">
  <div id="red-circle">
    <div class="red-title">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

В данном примере я привязывался к текущему времени и обращался к окружности с помощью `startTime` и интервальной функции, которая раз в 1мс обновляла текущее время и передавала `t` в функцию `drawPosition()`. Но вместо этого можно передавать `t` вызывая `drawPosition()` любым другим способом, например, подвязав этот процесс к скроллу.

Логику работы с окружностью подсмотрел в [данном видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBqYvgvN1rE) и адаптировал к ответу.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но ,к сожалению, offset-path не поддерживается safari

Comment: Да, согласен. Добавил в ответ еще один вариант подхода к данной задаче. Рассмотрите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 10):

### Решение pure SVG

Решение без скроллинга, так как его нет в SVG, но во втором примере будет скроллинг с использованием JS

Смотрите комментарии в коде, какие строчки реализуют анимацииии движения и увеличения

```html
<svg id="svg1" width="400" height="400" viewBox="10 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid grey">

    <!-- Траектория движения красного шарика -->
    <path id="track" d="m 401,28 c 0,0 -102,33 -103,156 -0.37,115 100,176 100.9,176.6" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" fill="none" id="theMotionPath"/>
   

    <!-- Красный круг, который будет перемещаться по траектории движения. -->
    <g id="dot">
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10" fill="red" />
    <text fill="black" font-size="24" x="-60" y="7">Text</text>  
      <!-- анимация движения красного шарика -->
      <animateMotion
      begin="svg1.click"
      dur="5s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
      fill="freeze"> 
         <mpath xlink:href="#track"></mpath>
      </animateMotion> 
   <!-- анимация увеличения красного шарика --> 
    <animateTransform  
          attributeName="transform" 
          type="scale" 
          values="1;2;1" 
          begin="svg1.click"
          dur="5s"
           repeatCount="indefinite"
          additive="sum"/>  
      </circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

### Решение SVG + JS scroll

```html
<style>
.verylong {
  height: 2000px;
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
</style>

<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid grey">

    <!-- Draw the outline of the motion path in grey, along with 2 small circles at key points -->
    <path d="m 401,28 c 0,0 -102,33 -103,156 -0.37,115 100,176 100.9,176.6" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" fill="none" id="theMotionPath"/>
   

    <!-- Красный круг, который будет перемещаться по траектории движения. -->
    <g id="dot">
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10" fill="red" />
    <text fill="black" font-size="24" x="-60" y="7">Text</text>
    </g>
</svg>

<div class="verylong">
</div>
<script>
function positionTheDot() {

  // Какой процент вниз по странице 
  var scrollPercentage = (document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);

  // Получить длину пути
  var path = document.getElementById("theMotionPath");
  var pathLen = path.getTotalLength();
  
  // Получить положение точки в <scrollPercentage> вдоль пути.
  var pt = path.getPointAtLength(scrollPercentage * pathLen);
  
  // Поместите красную точку в эту точку
  var dot = document.getElementById("dot");
  dot.setAttribute("transform", "translate("+ pt.x + "," + pt.y + ")");
  
};

// Обновить положение точки при получении события прокрутки.
window.addEventListener("scroll", positionTheDot);

// Установите начальную позицию точки.
positionTheDot();
</script>
```